# How can I resolve the glitching issue with my lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, lightbox

I implemented this lightbox into my website: https://codepen.io/darcyvoutt/pen/MaamWg/

```
// Function to reveal lightbox and adding YouTube autoplay
function revealVideo(div,video_id) {
var video = document.getElementById(video_id).src;
document.getElementById(video_id).src = video+'&autoplay=1'; // 
adding autoplay to the URL
document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'block';
}

// Hiding the lightbox and removing YouTube autoplay
function hideVideo(div,video_id) {
var video = document.getElementById(video_id).src;
var cleaned = video.replace('&autoplay=1',''); // removing 
autoplay form url
document.getElementById(video_id).src = cleaned;
document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';
}
```

However, after the fact I've noticed an issue with it:

If you open the lightbox, play the video, close the lightbox, and then open it again, the dimmer part of the lightbox loads in all wonky and in sections.

NOTE: this issue only shows up on desktop, not mobile.

I've tried messing with the code but for the life of me can't fix this issue. Any ideas on how this could be resolved?

Thank you!